# Am I using Custom Font the right way in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use a custom font on android and I'm not getting lucky. I think because I'm missing something. The source is loaded in Assets / fonts, and the code to load is \ e908 (In the image is escaped).
Any ideas?
Thank you!

[image: First Image]

[image: Second image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.iOS UIBarButtonItem With Unicode Character as Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781342/xamarin-ios-uibarbuttonitem-with-unicode-character-as-title)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396429/how-can-i-display-an-emoji-in-the-toolbar-title/38400542#38400542

Comment: @SushiHangover let me explain. I'm calling a character from a custom font I made. If I try to load "\u2699" it works. But when I try to load "\e908" from my custom font, it shows the text "\e908". I don't know if I'm calling it wrong or if it isn't loading the font correctly. It's the same custom font I use web and it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

To load "\e908" you have to get the INT value, treat it like a char and .ToString()
[image]